# Looping through elements by loading an external file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to JQuery and I am having some problems with some logic I am creating. My goal is to create a script that will load an external HTML file and select only the "div" tag which I want to loop through using .each. I have tried several variations and the furthest I have come is loading the HTML and adding it to a div tag. How can I go about acheiving this?

UPDATED:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#x").click(function(){
        $("#res").load('testfile.htm div', function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(index){

        });
        });
    });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Use jQuery load. You can specify an element you want to have from the loaded content. Something like `$('#res').load('testfile.htm #target');`

Comment: @putvande that would simplify his current code, but it's far from what he's trying to do.

Comment: Rather than only showing us what works, show us what you've tried that didn't work so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: Updated code above. I can select the div tags using load, but how can I loop through each div from the external page I loaded using .each? That is my roadblock at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solved your problem on jsfiddle.

Html looks like this :

```
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2" style="display:none;"></div>
```

and jQuery looks something like this.

```
 $("#id1").click(function () {
     $.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net', function (data) {
         $('#id2').html(data);
         $('#id2').find('div').each(function () {
             $("#id1").append($(this).html());
         });
     });
 });
```

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULfdh/1/).

Click on red div and wait for a min. it takes time to load the page.

Hope it solves the problem.

I have created a hidden div and loads the html page inside it temporarily and then filter it by div tags using .each and load the needed tags inside visible div.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks for the code sample. I never thought about trying it that way.